# Controlling Twisted based server from a web interface?

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web, twisted.internet

I created a server with a custom protocol using Twisted and I have clients that connect to the server on a specific port (say port 1234). I am looking to create a control interface for the server based on a web page of some sort. My research so far indicated Nevow is popular choice but I only need something very simple.

Say for example, every time a browser accesses the hello world page on port 8080, I send a message to clients connected on 1234.

I am a bit confused as to how I can connect these 2 together. I assume I would need to call Server.message from HelloResource.render_GET ?

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

    class Server(protocol.Protocol):
        def dataReceived(self, data):
            #do something on the server side

        def message(self)
            #send message to clients

    class HelloResource(Resource):
        isLeaf = True

        def render_GET(self,request):
            return "<html>Hello, world!</html>"

factory = protocol.Factory()
factory.protocol = Server
reactor.listenTCP(1234, factory)

reactor.listenTCP(8080, server.Site(HelloResource()))

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do things this way, your `Server.message` obviously has to be a `@classmethod`, and it has to have access to a list of clients, and send the message to each of them.

Something like this:

```
class Server(protocol.Protocol):
    clients = set()

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        #do something on the server side
        pass

    def connectionMade(self):
        Server.clients.add(self)

    def connectionLost(self):
        Server.clients.remove(self)

    @classmethod
    def message(cls):
        for client in cls.clients:
            client.transport.write('got GET request\n')
```

Now you can just call `Server.message()` from your `render_GET` method.

I'm not sure this is the best design—really, there are all kinds of better objects to hang a list of clients on than the protocol class—but it should work.

Answer (score 5):

This is very similar to [a question answered in the Twisted FAQ](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother).

Essentially, you need to make the protocol instances created by your factory accessible to the resources that make up your web server.

A simple way to do this is to have your factory keep a list of protocol instances (read about `buildProtocol` if you haven't yet) and then pass the factory instance to your `HelloResource` initializer, then have that initializer save the factory as an attribute on the `HelloResource` instance.

This would `HelloResource` access to a list of protocol instances - by way of the factory object it now has a reference to - which it could then iterate over and, for example, call methods on each protocol instance.